# R data.table merge duplicate rows and concatenate unique values

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to merge duplicate rows using data.table aggregate, but I need to figure out how to concatenate the non-duplicated columns as strings in the output:

```
dt = data.table(
  ensembl_id=c("ENSRNOG00000055068", "ENSRNOG00000055068", "ENSRNOG00000055068"),
  hsapiens_ensembl_id=c("ENSG00000196262", "ENSG00000236334", "ENSG00000263353"),
  chr=c(14, 14, 14),
  start=c(22706901, 22706901, 22706901),
  hsapiens_symbol=c("PPIA", "PPIAL4G", "PPIAL4A"),
  hsapiens_chr=c(7, 1, 1)
)
dt[, lapply(.SD, paste(...,sep=",")), by=ensembl_id] # <- need magic join/paste function
```

desired output:

```
           ensembl_id                             hsapiens_ensembl_id chr    start      hsapiens_symbol hsapiens_chr
1: ENSRNOG00000055068 ENSG00000196262,ENSG00000236334,ENSG00000263353  14 22706901 PPIA,PPIAL4G,PPIAL4A        7,1,1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `collapse` with `paste` instead of `sep` and include 'chr', 'start' also as grouping variables

```
library(data.table)
dt[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse=","), by = .(chr, start, ensembl_id)]
```

---

Or more compactly, with `toString`

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, toString), by = .(chr, start, ensembl_id)]
```

If we there are duplicates, get the `unique` values and `paste`

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(unique(x))), by = .(chr, start, ensembl_id)]
```